# Deezer Javascript SDK login not working

Tags: javascript, deezer

I've been trying to login with javascript SDK. And I am trying to login with this code:

```
DZ.init({
        appId  : 'MY_APP_ID',
        channelUrl : 'http://127.0.0.1/channel.html',
    player: {
        onload: function() {console.log('I am loaded')}
    }
});

  const login = () => {
    DZ.login(function(response) {
      console.log(response.authResponse);
        if (response.authResponse) {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            DZ.api('/user/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {perms: 'basic_access,email'});
  };
```

I am invoking login function with a login button. When login is invoked, new windows opens and asks to authorise the application, which is an expected behavior. But after this, it gets stuck as shown in the picture below:
[image]
And when I close the window, DZ does not get the access token although the access token is in the url as in the picture.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to initialize DZ with access token manually?
Also, my another qualm is that why js SDK does not need secret to initialize and login.

Comment: You might want to consider removing the screenshot that contains your access token.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. But I guess It won't matter as access token is temporary and I am just testing sdk.

Comment: Ah cool, just wanted to make sure you weren't accidentally posting credentials :)

Comment: It works now. I don't know how it got resolved automatically.